# Change NFS to use UDP instead of TCP

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, boot

I have a Debian 10 machine using NFS, it is using TCP protocol and I would like to change it to UDP.

This is output from the netbooted machine:

```
mount | grep 1
10.10.1.1:/remotesys on / type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,port=2049,timeo=7,retrans=10,sec=sys,local_lock=all,addr=10.10.1.1)
```

Where can I change that proto=tcp parameter permanently ? I would guess that this could be set in pxelinux.cfg/default file but I have not found any docs for this file so I have no idea about the syntax used here.

EDIT: What I have tried so far:

- Adding option "proto=udp" to /etc/exports (booted but tcp is still in use)
- Adding option "udp" to /etc/exports (booted but tcp is still in use)
- Adding option ",proto=udp" to nfsroot option in pxelinux.cfg/default (failed to boot - invalid option proto)
- Adding option "proto=udp" to pxelinux.cfg/default (booted but tcp is still in use)
- Adding option "udp" to pxelinux.cfg/default (booted but tcp is still in use)

Comment: Probably a [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt).

Comment: Yes probably, but where do I set it ? I would guess that this would be speicified somewhere in pxelinux.cfg/default but I have not found any documentation or syntax that is used in this file.

Answer (score 1):

in your `pxelinux.cfg/default`, you have probably specified something like this:

```
LABEL       Ubuntu
MENU LABEL  ^Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop
MENU DEFAULT
KERNEL     ubuntu-live/casper/vmlinuz
APPEND     root=/dev/nfs boot=casper ip=dhcp netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.xx.yy:/srv/ubuntu initrd=ubuntu-live/casper/initrd
```

[Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt) is the documentation for the nfsroot parameter inside the kernel command line. It says:

> `nfsroot=[<server-ip>:]<root-dir>[,<nfs-options>]`

so the answer to your question is, just append the `proto=udp` option to the nfsroot parameter as specified above, like this:

```
APPEND     root=/dev/nfs boot=casper ip=dhcp netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.xx.xx:/srv/ubuntu,proto=udp initrd=ubuntu-live/casper/initrd
```

**[edit]**
[This](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Config) Should be the documentation of the file format used for the `pxelinux.cfg/default` file.

**[edit2]**
After a long thorough search, I think I finally found the reason, why the options in the kernel command line are ignored:
[Bugreport for ubuntu casper](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/436829)

> 1. the scripts/casper script uses nfsmount, which doesn’t accept the -o
>    udp option. Changing »nfsmount« to »mount -t nfs« is a simple change and
>    works.

So the solution would be to fix the initrd in use for your image...

Comment: After chaning the file my machine cannot boot: Retrying nfs mount ... nfsmount: bad option 'proto'

Comment: I removed the comma character and it works now: APPEND     root=/dev/nfs boot=casper ip=dhcp netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.xx.xx:/srv/ubuntu proto=udp initrd=ubuntu-live/casper/initrd to make it work

Comment: Problem is that mounts on the netbooted machine still shows it is booted over TCP protocol.

Comment: without the comma, it is not an nfs option - and the kernel probably ignored the proto= parameter. According to https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs proto=udp is only available for nfs version 2 and 3, and recent kernels use NFS v4 ...

Comment: So how can I set it to udp ? In the docs you posted it says this parameter is available for version 4 as well.

Comment: maybe this question helps ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205529/nfs-mount-nfs-protocol-not-supported

Comment: I tried to add it to /etc/exports, it booted up but it still shows protocol tcp.

Comment: read my newest edit, I've updated my answer...

Comment: I can't get udp or proto=udp to even work as a mount option for any nfs mount nowadays.  Using nfsmount, mount, or mount.nfs.  Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a mount option :

```
mount -o udp server:/export /mnt
```

**NOTE** transferring big files over udp might result in data loss!